# How can I apply certain DRL files to certain facts

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

Let us suppose that I work at a large manufacturing company.  I am monitoring the quality of the company's sales data.  The various regional managers each have their own requirements for the sales from their region.  Each of the 8 regional managers supply me with a DRL file that is to be applied to sales from his own region only, and they will make frequent adjustments to the DRLs.

Let us assume that I am working with a Sale objects, each of which includes a region attribute.  I must not apply rules to sales from the wrong region. If I accidentally apply the Pacific Northwest rules to the Ohio River Valley sales then I will be fired!

I can think of three ways to do this:

1. Trust (and verify) each regional manager to include a region = "..." term in the LHS of his rules every time he submits a new one. Load all DRL files into the Kie session and run all Sales through.
2. Divide my List<Sale> into 8 region-specific lists and run each list against the corresponding DRL file.
3. Make Sale abstract and implement PacificNorthwestSale, OhioRiverValleySale, etc. on the theory that a given region's DRL file will probably not try to refer to region-specific sales from another region.

Is there a better way?  Is there some way that I can add another LHS condition (region = "...") to all the rules in a DRL? Or some other way I can enforce this policy without doing:

- multiple rule executions
- or manual verification that all rules specify the appropriate region?

Answer (score 3):

#1 is out since there is no foolproof way to ascertain the inclusion of a region constraint in all rules. (This, of course, makes you wonder: will those regional guys be good enough to write theirs rules correctly, over and above the region constraint? How so? Will one of these rules calculate their bonus?)

#2 is safe and sound. It requires a little extra handling but that's negligible.

#3 makes the Java code base needlessly complex. Essentially, matching against distinct subclasses of a class, all other things being equal, is nothing but a sugared version of #1. The only advantage would be that checking is easier, e.g., you could run a simple grep over each DRL.

#4 is the one I would adopt if running all in a single session is more convenient that what is required for #2. To do so, combine the DRL files programmatically, with a little "glue":

```
package what.ever;
import this.and.that.*;

agenda-group "PacificNorthwest"
// DRL from Pacific-Northwest

agenda-group "OhioRiverValley"
// DRL from Ohio River Valley
```

To run, set the focus in the app driver to each of these eight agenda-groups and then insert the appropriate facts, making sure to clean WM after one region is done.